# Play 2 Twitter authentication

Tags: scala, twitter, playframework-2.0

I have a Play 2 web app where users can login using twitter (`/authenticate/twitter`). After some time after the server is started, the login no longer works and I receive:

```
    Feb 17, 2015 8:22:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [play] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: This request was timed out after 60000 ms
        at play.core.server.servlet25.Play2Servlet25RequestHandler.onFinishService(RequestHandler.scala:36)
        at play.core.server.servlet.Play2GenericServletRequestHandler.apply(RequestHandler.scala:371)
        at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$$anonfun$handleRequest$2.apply(Play2Server.scala:64)
        at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$$anonfun$handleRequest$2.apply(Play2Server.scala:64)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.core.server.servlet.Play2WarServer$.handleRequest(Play2Server.scala:64)
        at play.core.server.servlet.GenericPlay2Servlet.service(Play2CommonServlet.scala:36)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:680)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I simply have no clue from where to start the investigation. If I restart the server login works fine for a while... Can you give a hint?

I am using [SecureSocial](http://securesocial.ws/) for doing twitter authentication. Application is deployed on Elastic Beanstalk using Tomcat server.

Comment: What is your tokenDuration? The default 60 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your service doing? Have you tried taking a thread dump?

This is quite likely due to running on the servlet API - especially servlet 2.5. Play is an asynchronous framework, servlet 2.5 is completely synchronous. You're asking for trouble trying to run an asynchronous webapp in a synchronous web server. If I were you, I would use a platform that supports Play natively, such as Heroku.

Comment: Updating my packaging of war to servlet 3.0 seems that have a significat impact (Tomcat 7 with servlet 3 supports async)... Thanks a lot for the point.